# How do I identify O(nlogn) exactly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have understood O(logn) in a sense that it increases quickly but with larger inputs, the rate of increase retards. 
I am not able to completely understand

1. O(nlogn)
2. the difference between an algorithm with complexity nlogn and complexity n + logn.

I could use a modification of the phone book example and/or some basic python code to understand the two queries

Comment: [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+log(x),+x*log(x),+x%2B+log(x),+x+%3D+1..32) and read chapter about complexity in any algorithm book

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you think of `O(n ^ 2)`?
Personally, I like to think of it as doing `O(n)` work `O(n)` times.

A contrived `O(n ^ 2)` algorithm would be to iterate through all pairs of numbers in `0, 1, ..., n - 1`

```
def print_pairs(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            print('({},{})'.format(i, j))
```

Using similar logic as above, you could do `O(log n)` work `O(n)` times and have a time complexity of `O(n log n)`.

As an example, we are going to use binary search to find all indices of elements in an array.

Yes, I understand this is a dumb example but here I don't want to focus on the usefulness of the algorithm but rather the complexity. For the sake of the correctness of our algorithm let us assume that the input array is sorted. Otherwise, our binary search does not work as intended and could possibly run indefinitely.

```
def find_indices(arr):
    indices = []
    for num in arr:
        index = binary_search(arr, 0, len(arr), num)
        indices.append(index)
    return indices

def binary_search(arr, l, r, x): 

    # Check base case 
    if r >= l: 

        mid = l + (r - l)/2

        # If element is present at the middle itself 
        if arr[mid] == x: 
            return mid 

        # If element is smaller than mid, then it  
        # can only be present in left subarray 
        elif arr[mid] > x: 
            return binary_search(arr, l, mid-1, x) 

        # Else the element can only be present  
        # in right subarray 
        else: 
            return binary_search(arr, mid + 1, r, x) 

    else: 
        # Element is not present in the array 
        return -1
```

As for your second question, 
surely, `log n << n` as n tends to infinity so

`O(n + log n) = O(n)`

In theory, the `log n` is dwarfed by the `n` as we get arbitrarily large so we don't include it in our Big O analysis.

Juxtaposed to practice, where you might want to consider this extra `log n` work if your algorithm is suffering performance and/or scaling issues.

Comment: Great answer. I would add that the Big O notation defines `log n` more as an additional level between `constant`, e.g. 1, and `n`. This does not really have to be exactly `log n` (although it often is, given a large enough n). If you have two loops, the outer one iterates over `n` while the inner one starts small and gets larger (or the other way around), or it has some clever element-skipping strategy then you most likely have an `n long n` case

Answer (score 4):

`log n` is a much slower growing function than `n`. When computer scientists speak of big-O, they are interested in the growth of the function for extremely large input values. What the function does near some small number or inflection point is immaterial.

Many common algorithms have time complexity of `n log n`. For example, [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) requires `n` steps to be taken `log_2(n)` times as the input data is split in half. After studying the algorithm, the fact that its complexity is `n log n` may come to you by intuition, but you could arrive at the same conclusion by studying the recurrence relation that describes the (recursive) algorithm--in this case `T(n) = 2 * T(n / 2) + n`. More generally but perhaps least intuitively, the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) can be applied to arrive at this `n log n` expression. In short, don't feel intimidated if it isn't immediately obvious why certain algorithms have certain running times--there are many ways you can take to approach the analysis.

Regarding "complexity n + log n", this isn't how big-O notation tends to get used. You may have an algorithm that does `n + log n` work, but instead of calling that `O(n + log n)`, we'd call that `O(n)` because `n` grows so much faster than `log n` that the `log n` term is negligible. The point of [big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example) is to state only the growth rate of the fastest growing term.

Compared with `n log n`, an `log n` algorithm is less complex. If `log n` is the time complexity of inserting an item into a self-balancing search tree, `n log n` would be the complexity of inserting `n` items into such a structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Grokking algorithms](https://www.manning.com/books/grokking-algorithms) awesome book that explains algorithms complexity detection (among other things) exhaustively and by a very simple language.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, algorithms with complexity O(n + log n) and complexity O(n) are the same, as the log n term becomes negligible when n grows.

O(n) grows linearly. The slope is constant.

O(n log n) grows super-linearly. The slope increases (slowly).